# How to upload large CSV into Workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

So i have a CSV file which im trying to import/ create a new table in my database. im using MySQL Workbench to do is. But the file is quite huge around 40mb, when im importing after sometime im getting this error

`Row import failed with error: ('Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE', 1243)`

What is this error and how can i fix this?

Comment: Do you use workbench's built-inimport function or do you have a custom code to import the data?

Comment: using workbench built in import function

Comment: Then you have probably found a bug. Make dure you have the latest version of workbench. If this does not help, then you have to use load data infile to manually load the data or use a different gui.

Comment: Hi, I run into this problem today and seem to been able to work around it this way.
Running the latest version of MySQL workbench as of 2020-12-14.

The problem occured while trying to import to one table while already importing to another.